# Appending li content into form input value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<li>` with values gotten searching on a `form input` from database. The results are `echo` out in a `li`. I wan such that when i click on one particular `li` the content of the `li` `appends` into the `form input value`. Below are the codes i have tried.

**JavaScript**

```
//calls php script as user searches
function searchd() {
var searchTxt = $("input[name='deptfrom']").val();

$.post("deptsearch.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function (echo) {
    $('.airSearch ul').html(echo);
});
}

//supposed to append the echoed php results into the <input value="">
$('.airSearch ul li').click(function() {
    $('#deptform').value.append($('.airSearch ul li').innerHTML);
});
```

What are the issues with getting the search results into the form input value on click? There's something obviously wrong with my code. Please any help would do.

Comment: try searching for event delegation

Comment: What your `Ajax` returns?

Comment: @AAShakil Please can you help me with how a`ajax` can be the issue.

Comment: @diagold Do you have `HTML` that could be provided?

Comment: Try this `$("#deptform").val($("#deptform").val()+$(".airSearch ul li").innerHTML)); `

Comment: Have you tried `append()`, `after()`, or `insertAfter()`?

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

I can't confidently say what's the error in your code because I don't have huge & confidential knowledge about `jQuery`. But, I can give you another way so that you can perform this action.

I'm not sure if `JQuery` has such function like `value.append` as you've provided in your code. Though, you could use your browser's console to try to know the exception.

---

### Solution

**Try this code**

```
$('.airSearch ul li').click(function(){
 $('#deptform').val($('#deptform').val()+$('.airSearch ul li').innerHTML);
});
```

It will be better if you use `$('.airSearch ul li').text();`

So, the above code will change the `value` as you've wanted. It will append text of `li` to the expected `input`.